# Merging IEnumerable and removing duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that exacts data from an XML and returns an `IEnumerable<Foo>`.  I am trying to create a method that will merge the results from 2 different XML's files into a single `IEnumerable` and remove any duplicate data that may be found

A duplicate in this case is defined as 2 `Foo` objects that have the same `Name` property even if the other data is different.  If there is a duplicate, I always want to keep the `Foo` from the first `IEnumerable` and discard the 2nd.

Am I on the right track with this LINQ query, or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> MergeElements(XElement element1, XElement element2)
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> firstFoos = GetXmlData(element1); // get and parse first set
    IEnumerable<Foo> secondFoos = GetXmlData(element2); // get and parse second set

    var result = firstFoos.Concat(secondFoos)
                          .GroupBy(foo => foo.Name)
                          .Select(grp => grp.First());

    return result;
}
```

The biggest concern I have with this code is that I am not certain the duplicate filtering rules I want will be guaranteed.  I know `Concat` will just append `secondFoos` to the end of `firstFoos`, but when calling `GroupBy()`, will the resulting `IGrouping` object always have elements in the same order as the source data?

Comment: Can you implement `Equals()` (and preferably also `IEquatable<Foo>`) on `Foo`, to compare by `Name`?

Comment: @svick `Foo` already does that through overriding `Equals()` (although it does not implement `IEquatable`, but I can add it).  I thought of using `Distinct()`, but I've read it is unordered, so I was concerned my filtering rules would not be guaranteed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With things like this, it's usually best to look at the documentation.

Is your approach with `GroupBy()` going to work? [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx):

> Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.

Can you use `Distinct()` to do the same thing more concisely? [No](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) (at least you shouldn't depend on it):

> The `Distinct` method returns an **unordered** sequence that contains no duplicate values.

Is there some other way? Yes, you can use [`Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union enumerates *first* and *second* in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded.

So, I think the best way to do it is:

```
var result = firstFoos.Union(secondFoos);
```

Comment: Great answer.  I was pretty sure `Distinct()` was not my solution, but somehow missed `Union()` in the documentation.